low fps on ubuntu 24.04 laptop
I recently purchased a laptop ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Vivobook Go 15 E1504FA. And installed ubuntu 24.04. I have a problem in games I have a small fps, although the processor is not fully loaded. I tried to find drivers for my gpu but i can't find anything.  Also in hardinfo in the section comes out this: AMD AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi, raphael_Mendocino, LLVM 17.0.6, DRM 3.57, 6.8.0-35-generic)
4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1. I don't think there are any normal drivers for my system.
For example, saints row the third does not want to go on ultra. I do not think that the game of 2011 will not be able to run normally on my laptop. Also minecraft with simple shaders also lags even though the processor is loaded at 20%. I tried to play through Wayland and xorg, but it still lagging.
i dont find drivers on asus and amd sites.
update- inxi result:
Device-1: AMD Mendocino driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: ShineTech USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 46.0 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
    renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi raphael_mendocino LLVM 17.0.6 DRM
    3.57 6.8.0-35-generic)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland


When you run inxi -G what does it say for your driver?

@mchid i edited post and sent info from inxi

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
